# Change onmousemove speed 3D view

Tags: javascript

I asked this yesterday :
*...."I want to know if it is possible to reduce the speed of the mouse when the camera moves in a div 3d .
The link to the application are here
[a link] (http://codepen.io/brantholt/pen/sEgJb)
I would to not close all the side divs .
Here is the example with less speed of the camera where the sides do not close all divs...."*

You are right Amit, my question is not so clear so I'll rephrase and apologize for my poor English level.

I want to know if it is possible to reduce the speed of the style 3D view of the product is set to class " perspective" but the movement of the web , create the script by `window.onmousemove = function (e )` to `var x = e.clientX ;
  var y = e.clientY ;` .
When I try to slow down by the value `originX.toFixed ( 4)` in `originX.toFixed ( 0 )` , the view is static without moving. What function can be changed in the script to reduce the speed 3D view  ?
Thank you !

Comment: If the original question was too unclear and you want to rephrase it, you should just edit the original question instead of posting another one and referring back to the original.

Comment: Sory folx, I am new in this post, in the next questions attempt meet the standards . So, someone could help me ?